# Select dropdown fit width to current selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a non-JavaScript way (or at most a native JavaScript way) of making a `select` element's width match the current selection? When clicked on, the dropdown will be the width of the longest `option`, but the `select` itself should only take up as much space as it needs.

I am trying to put a `select` element inline with some text, so something with a fixed width like this looks funny:

```
<p>you are currently viewing
the <select style="width:200px;"><option>Awesome</option></select>
option</p>
```

It will end up looking like `you are current viewing the Awesome         ▼ option`. I want the width to fit the selection, so it looks smooth like `you are current viewing the Awesome ▼ option`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue a few months ago, but I couldn't find a pure CSS-HTML solution. However, I've found a good example in js with jQuery ,it's not heavy at all : http://jsfiddle.net/kn9DF/77/

```
<script>
   function setSelectWidth() {
       var sel = $('#sel');
       $('#templateOption').text( sel.val() );
       sel.width( $('#template').width() * 1.03 );
   }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks! i more or less used the same technique behind your example. except what i did is create a `div`, move it off screen (`top:-10000px`), and then apply the same font family, size, etc. to it as my dropdown, fill it with the selected option text, and then copy its width. this allowed me to not have to use extra markup and only about ~20 lines of JS.